# Remove HTTP header on ASP.Net Core 2.2 InProcess

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2

I have an ASP.Net Core 2.2 Web API project that is using InProcess hosting model. I need to remove certain HTTP headers from the response such as **Server** and **X-Powered-By**. All the answers I have found lead to *ConfigureKestrel()* or manually editing the web.config file. However:

1. I am not using Kestrel since I am InProcess
2. The web.config is auto-generated when publishing the app

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, `web.config` *is* autogenerated when you publish, but it is smart enough to update any existing `web.config` you might already have in your project.

Comment: Interestingly enough, if I hit preview file on web.config then it messes it up but if I publish then it does effectively merge it. However, although I am able to remove the X-Powered-By, the _Server_ HTTP headers still shows up.

Comment: I can get rid of the Server HTTP header by doing the following in web.config
`<security>
   <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true" />
 </security>`

This would work for IIS10. Previous version relies on outbound rewrite rule.